# SAS: retrieve value matching id from another data set

Tags: sas

I have one data set with repeated ID's as follows:

```
## DATASET 1 ##
 ID  val1 val2
 1    2     10
 1    3     9
 ..
 1    4    8
 2    5    3
 ...
```

I have second one like this:

```
  ## DATASET 2 ##
  ID  num
  1    48
  2    30
  ...
```

And I want to be able to look at the ID in dataset 2, take the num from the ID, and repeat it alongside the same ID in dataset 1 like this:

```
  ## DATASET 1 (new) ##
  ID  val1 val2  num
  1    2     10   48
  1    3     9    48
  ..
  1    4     8    48 
  2    5     3    30
  ...
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables with a left join

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select t1.id, t1.val1, t1.val2, t2.num
from one t1 left join two t2
on t1.id = t2.id
;
quit;
```

or using a data step merge

```
data want;
merge one two;
by id;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! But what are "one" and "two" versus t1 and t2? It works if I just remove "one" and "two"

Comment: It is a reference to the table, in that case I reference the table `one` with `t1` for example. It works just fine without it.